# How to redirect user after login to a desired page according to their role?

Tags: php, session

I have 2 roles called Member and Admin. However, as for now to distinguish between sessions, I only did an if else statements. Like this,

```
session_start();
$msg = "";


if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 ###############################
} else { 
 ################################

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
 #################################
   <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['role'] == "Admin") {
            ?>
          ################################
          ################################
   <?php
        } elseif ($_SESSION['role'] == "Member") {
            ?>
          #################################
          #################################
```

The following hash signs are just putting in what a member should see and what an admin should see. This page that contains the following codes are in doLogin.php after the credentials in login.php are inserted in. However, I find a trouble to click back on home.php for admin as basically the home for admin is actually doLogin.php. Often there will be a "Confirm Resubmission form" error appeared.

What I wanted to do now is when the admin logs in, it should be directed to a new page which is admin.php containing all the details of what the admin should see. How do i do this?

Comment: `header("Location: http://example.com/page.php");` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `header location` to redirect

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
if ($_SESSION['role'] == "Admin") {

    header("Location:admin.php");
    exit;

} elseif ($_SESSION['role'] == "Member") {

    header("Location:member.php");
    exit;
}
}
?>
```